# "The server requested authentication method unknown to the client" Error after trying to connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

While working on my project I wrote a simple PHP file to connect to my MySQL database.

```
<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $dbname = 'forum-tutorial';
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname)
?>
```

Though when I run that from localhost it just gives me:
Warning: mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in C:\wamp64\www\forum-tutorial\dbconn.php on line 6

as well as a number of other errors i assume come from the same thing.

I was told to 1) change my PHP version to 7.2 which i tried a few older version but that didn't work. and 2) I tried replacing the file with this script:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
```

Please note that the password field on the above script is blank because my SQL login credentials are the default "root" and blank password. Can someone help me fix this error so i can successfully connect to the database?

Comment: Did you change `mysqlUsername` or `root`? Can you include `SHOW CREATE USER root@localhost` in your question?

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I did change mysqlUsername to root but i forgot to edit that in the question.